# TryRemove a key-value pair from ConcurrentDictionary in C#

Tags: c#, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

The scenario I have is I want a method on `ConcurrentDictionary` like this.

```
bool TryRemove(TKey key, TValue value) {
    // remove the value IF the value passed in == dictionary[key]
    // return false if the key is not in the dictionary, or the value is not equal
}
```

Is there a way to do this concurrently?  I'm struggling to find an answer for this scenario, even though it seems like this is a common use case.

I could do something like this, but I want to avoid a lock if I'm already using a `ConcurrentDictionary`.  I'd also have to have locks on `GetOrAdd()` or `AddOrUpdate()` calls elsewhere.  It just seems like there should be a better way with a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> dict = ...;

/// stuff

int keyTryToRemove = 1337;
string valTryToRemove = "someValue";

bool success = false;
lock(keyTryToRemove) {
    string val;
    if (dict.TryRemove(keyTryToRemove, out val)) {
        if (val == valTryToRemove) {
            success = true;
        }
        else { // reinsert value, UGLY!
            dict[keyTryToRemove] = val;
            success = false;
        }
    } else {
        success = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It already exists: [ConcurrentDictionary.TryRemove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287129(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What about doing a `TryGetValue` and the a `Remove` if it returns true and the value matches?  You'd still need the lock though.

Comment: @Igor That removes based on the key and returns the value, the OP want to remove the entry if the key and value both match.  They even use it in there attempt.

Comment: @Igor that's exactly what I don't want.  I want to conditionally remove the value, only if it matches the value I passed to it.

Comment: @juharr - Ah, I missed that.

Comment: The best option is to write an extension method and to implement your own lock on the Dictionary instance passed in. Inside the lock there is no need to call any of the existing methods that also lock.

Comment: @Igor if I do this, then I'd need access to the same lock inside the extension method that I need to use on the `GetOrAdd()` and `AddOrUpdate()` calls, right?

Comment: @JohnCarpenter - not sure why the down vote, its was a good question (IMO). +1 from me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) class implements (although explicitly) [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx), thus [`ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx), you can simply cast it to the later and use [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bye7h94w(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
bool success = ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)dict).Remove(
    new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
```

The [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,4d3f2a076a068c2e) internally uses the same thread safe method (passing additionally the value to be checked) as the public `TryRemove` method - exactly as it should be.

**Edit:** Generally speaking, the method in question can be made available for any type implementing `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` (or more precisely `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`) like `Dictionary`, `ConcurrentDictionary` etc. by introducing a custom extension method like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool TryRemove<TKey, TValue>(this ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        return source.Remove(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }
}
```

so the sample code becomes simply:

```
bool success = dict.TryRemove(key, value);
```

Comment: woah, that's cool, and I think exactly what I'm looking for.  One question, this is still thread safe, right?

Comment: @JohnCarpenter - it is, I just checked.

Comment: It uses the same internal implementation as the public `TryRemove` - [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,4d3f2a076a068c2e)

Answer (score -1):

I'd do something like this

```
bool success = false;
lock(lockForDictionary) 
{
    string val;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(keyTryToRemove, out val) && val == valTryToRemove) 
    {
        dict.Remove(keyTryToRemove);
        success = true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is `lockForDictionary`?

Comment: Yeah, this is much better than what I did in my answer.  Would it be possible only to lock on the key?  I think yes, but I wanted to verify that's the case

Comment: @JohnCarpenter No, you want your lock to be for the specific dictionary instance.  I'm leaving that for you to determine how to implement, but I would also not make use of the dictionary itself as the lock, but just a `object` specifically created just for locking on.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter How are you going to guarantee the key is thread safe?  You never want to use an object that is owned by an external entity as a lock

Answer (score -1):

Below is a piece of code that simplify the steps a bit.

```
readonly object _locker = new object();
readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> _dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

public bool TryRemove(int key, string value)
{
    var success = false;
    lock (_locker)
    {
        if (_dict.ContainsKey(key) && _dict[key] == value)
        {
            string val;
            success = _dict.TryRemove(key, out val);
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

With that said, it seems the goal is non atomic in nature and this is why we have the need for a lock.  It's important to ask, what is your goal and can you express the goal in an atomic way.  2 useful methods of ConcurrentDictionary include TryUpdate and AddOrUpdate.  Would any of those methods help?

Comment: You answered after someone already posted an atomic solution, though I appreciate the effort you put into your answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Each answer on here is slightly different. These differences can have a big performance difference in multi-threaded code. In the code above, the value in the dictionary is checked without removal.  This is big since adding and removing is an expensive operation.  Only when the conditions for removal is met is the value removed.